# if just one cell or range("b2:e2") data was changed, how can i copy each data to another sheet.cell(i,1) one-variable-at-a-time as vba code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

for example, there are external data in (B2: E2) which variant is consistently changing by itself.
And, I want to copy each of that into sheet2 and each cell one-variable-at-a-time. 
such as,

```
cells(1,1) = 200 cell(1,2) = alpa
cells(2,1) = 250 cell(2,2) = veta
cells(i,1) = ___ cell(i,2) = _____
```

and so on.
so how can I type code to work like this? 
and if my English typing is so difficult to understand, I apologize 
because I'm South Korean and I can't speak fluently but, I can get your saying.
I can't find out exactly how to solve this in my country.
I hope your help, thank you.

Comment: How are `B2:E2` updated? Do they have formula(s) that are refreshing? Or a data query?

Comment: well, tell the truth, I use DDE system from HTS which is interconnected in excel. so it reflects the real-time market price on specific cells and it's always updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the below code you could copy the new value into the same column of sheet2.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ColNo As Long, ColLR As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    If Not Intersect(Target, ws1.Range("B2:E2")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then

        ColNo = Target.Column

        With ws2

            ColLR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColNo).End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(ColLR + 1, ColNo).Value = Target.Value

        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I really appreciated your comments but there is some error so it doesn't work.  I can get why this happened.  I use the DDE system from HTS which is interconnected in excel. so it reflects the real-time market price on specific cells and it's always updated. Invalid outside procedure which is has to be considered?

Comment: i m here to help. could you please be more specific? where is the error? what is the error?

Comment: really thank you. um....can you hold on a minute? because my English typing is so slow I can wait a day or more. so I want you to keep your composure I don't want to make you wait so long for you

Comment: I used your code in my excel visual basic sheet1 and it happened nothing.

Comment: O.K I uploaded.